# How to configure SSH ControlPath correctly if %r contains slash?

Tags: ssh, configuration

The username contains slashes. If I use standard `~/.ssh/sockets/master-%r@%h:%p` as the ConfigPath, ssh would complain that
unix_listener: cannot bind to path `~/.ssh/sockets/master-username/which/contains/slash@host_ip:port.s5FLlcqcHkethwd0`: No such file or directory.

It seems the slash in the username is interpreted as path seperator.

How could I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

That's what the `%C` token is for. From the docs:

```
%C    Hash of %l%h%p%r.
```

Since it generates a hash of the username (and other data), you don't need to worry about your username containing weird characters.

For example, if I run:

```
ssh -M -o ControlPath=/tmp/control-%C alice@example.com
```

I might find a socket named:

```
/tmp/control-3ba0719e3df95b719713923899a65f64655dea64
```

Comment: Thanks! saved my day!

Comment: @WeiQiu Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.